# How to change login password of ubuntu from console?

Tags: ubuntu

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and the log in screen hangs after boot so i want to remove password from log in.
I am trying to change from console of tty-1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the command 'passwd' to change or remove your password from the comamnd line. Of course it requires the current password to change or remove it.